# ruby shoes: create modal window

Tags: ruby, shoes

Is there an attribute to create a modal window e.g. one that has complete focus.

we cannot use confirm/alert etc. and i'm assuming i create a window/dialog, but its asynchronous and exits after creation?

i.e. something like

```
 dialog :title => '', :modal=>true do
```

- googled, been through all ruby manuals and no reference to modal/focus?
- checked out the source code and had a look for modal/keep focus type parameters - couldn't find anything?
- i've come across suggests for Ruby/Tk (similar type of stuff) where people have to wait in a loop for close events and exit. this seems a bit cumbersome?

any thoughts out there?

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to launch another window alongside the main window? That is well supported:

```
Shoes.app do
  para 'first app'
  button "launch second" do
    Shoes.app width: 180, height: 60  do
      para 'I am a second app!'
    end
  end
end
```

Although that is an entirely new window, so it might not be what you want. If you want an all focus window that is essentially part of the app and greys out the main application, then no that is not possible :( Created an [issue for modals](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues/1223) though.

Comment: thanks PragTob - a 2nd window is definitely possible buts is the taking primary and only focus that is the bit i think is not possible